# will autocorrect reset when turned off?

Tags: autocorrect

If I turn autocorrect off for a short amount of time, will it forget the corrections it knows? on an iPod touch 5th generation, it will often mess with audio, and I would like to turn it on and off, but I am worried it will get rid of certain phrases that it autocorrects because of me using them so much.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary will NOT reset from turning off auto correct. (i.e. `Settings` > `General` > `Keyboards` > `Auto Correct`)

To reset the dictionary visit `Settings` > `General` > `Reset` > `Reset Keyboard Dictionary`